# Testers cannot fully install my iOS app. They were able to up until two weeks ago

Tags: ios, installation

I have an `iOS` app that I generate a `.ipa` file for from my staging build. I then uploaded the file to a testers platform so they can install and test. The last two builds we have tried to do this with will not complete installation. My issue is I can not figure out if the issue is from my end or from the end of the platform that I load it onto. Here is the error message I get in the logs. Does anyone know what can I do to fix this or at least figure out if it is me or the platform that is causing the issue?

> Oct 26 21:07:54 Roberts-iPhone6 mobile_installation_proxy[38912]
>   : 0x100384000 handle_install: Installation failed: Error
>   Domain=LaunchServicesError Code=0 "The operation couldnít be
>   completed. (LaunchServicesError error 0.)" UserInfo=0x15d54cab0
>   {Error=ApplicationVerificationFailed, ErrorDetail=-402620392,
>   ErrorDescription=Failed to verify code signature of
>    : 0xe8008018 (Invalid signing certificate (it may have
>   expired or been revoked))}

Comment: can you check your distribution certificate. and check your used distribution certificate's Expire date. if your certificate is not expires then check your certificates are installed in Xcode -> Preference -> Account -> select your app ID's -> view details and tap on reload button. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the info Mihir. I will look into it. I am noticing something odd in my question. It looks like someone came and edited my question but failed to match the tenses. Can you please put it back so it reads properly. Thank  you.

Comment: Please check the edited History. I am not edited your Question. For check Who was edit your question Please Click on "edited yesterday ".

Comment: Hi Mihir. Sorry I did not intend the for you to think I meant that you in particular had edited my message. I was hoping the person who did edit it would read the comment. I did take your advice and I looked at who edited it. I must say this is a great site but why do they allow users to edit questions with grammar that is worse than the original posting? The great news is we did figure out what was wrong with our installs. We needed everyone to update their iTunes accounts. Apparently our Xcode certificates were not compatible with old versions of iTunes. Thanks for the help.